# Why is the shape of this array not two-dimensional?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Using Numpy I tried creating an array from one of the columns out of a dataframe. This array I created, however, its size is (48,) where 48 is the number of rows, instead of (48,1) which I expected. Why is this the case? I thought any array created from a numpy dataframe had to have a defined number of rows and columns

Below is the relevant code, output, and dataset represented by df

```py
y = df.iloc[:, -1]

a=y.shape//Output is (48,)

00  0   1
0   1   0.0 45.0
1   1   0.0 48.0
2   1   0.5 67.0
3   1   1.5 59.5
4   1   1.5 62.4
5   1   1.5 84.4
6   1   1.5 82.0
7   1   1.5 79.5
8   1   3.0 64.8
9   1   3.0 67.4
10  1   3.0 82.6
11  1   3.0 78.2
12  1   3.0 80.4
13  1   3.5 71.3
14  1   3.5 70.5
15  1   3.5 75.0
16  1   3.5 80.9
17  1   3.5 83.2
18  1   4.0 78.4
19  1   4.0 74.2
20  1   4.0 81.5
21  1   4.0 68.9
22  1   4.5 68.3
23  1   4.5 78.5
24  1   4.5 75.9
25  1   4.5 81.6
26  1   4.5 83.2
27  1   4.5 86.1
28  1   4.5 87.4
29  1   5.0 72.8
30  1   5.0 75.0
31  1   5.0 75.6
32  1   5.0 79.3
33  1   5.0 82.4
34  1   5.0 86.3
35  1   5.0 90.2
36  1   5.0 93.4
37  1   5.5 79.5
38  1   5.5 81.4
39  1   5.5 83.2
40  1   5.5 85.7
41  1   5.5 91.4
42  1   5.5 98.5
43  1   5.5 94.3
44  1   6.0 81.2
45  1   6.0 85.4
46  1   6.0 91.0
47  1   6.0 94.3
```

Comment: While an array from a whole dataframe is 2d, the array from a Series is 1d.  In `numpy` a shape like (48,) is more common than (48,1).  When `broadcasting` a (48,) may be expanded to (1,48).  But it's easy to change the shape to (48,1), e.g. `y[:,None]`

Comment: you can use `np.reshape()` to change the shape of your array data.

Answer (score 0):

The result is a 1D array. If its length is N, then it can be represented as N-by-1 or 1-by-N vector, as we were told in the linear algebra class. But this approach has some issues that we don't want to deal with in coding.

Issue 1. We need to choose if the answer is N-by-1 or 1-by-N vector and stick to it. However, sometimes we have a preference for one over another, and, therefore, we need to do additional actions.

Issue 2. If the size of an array is (1, N) or (N, 1), we need to access its elements using two indexes, for example, `arr[0, N-1]` or `arr[N-1, 0]`. It is confusing -- after all, it is a 1D vector, and a single index suffices. We wish to access its elements as `arr[N-1]`, i.e., by using a single index. In linear algebra notations, it would mean that the shape is `(N)`, which looks awkward. The shape is a tuple, and a one-element tuple is written using a comma as `(N, ).`

Such a twist solves the issue. Now we can use linear multiplication from both right and left sides and access the elements using a single index.